# Proxmoxer : how to create LXC container specifying disk size

Tags: python, lxc, proxmox

I'm running version 5.2 of proxmox, and 1.0.2 of proxmoxer python library. Latest as of today.

So far I didn't manage to create a LXC container specifying a disk size and will always default to 4G. I didn't find this option in Proxmox documentation...

I am using :

```
node.lxc.create(vmid=204,
    ostemplate='local:vztmpl/jessie-TM-v0.3.tar.gz',
    hostname='helloworld',
    storage='raid0',
    memory=2048,
    swap=2048,
    cores=2,
    password='secret',
    net0='name=eth0,bridge=vmbr0,ip=dhcp')
```

Adding something like `rootfs='raid0:204/vm-204-disk-1.raw,size=500G'` will disable disk image creation and look for an already existing image.
Anyway, I don't really know where to go next. Am I supposed to create a disk image before hand? I didn't find how to do this for LXC. No problems with qemu.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time spent on this, looking at the code of proxmox ansible module helped.
So, to specify a disk size when creating a LXC container using Proxmox API, one need to simply HTTP POST :

```
rootfs=10
```

For a 10G HDD. Without anything else.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to create your container by the **web interface** ?

Can you access it ?

Comment: Sorry for delay, yes creating using web interface is not an issue. It was more of an REST API question in fact.